# Reformatting JSON

Tags: json, json.net

I have a JSON like this,

```
 {

      "row_elements": [
            "[Product].[Corporation].[Corporation]",
            "[Product].[Int Product Name].[Int Product Name]",
            "[Product].[Local Product Name].[Local Product Name]"
    ]
}
```

I want to format this as ,

```
{    "row_elements": [
            {
                "level": "[Product].[Corporation].[Corporation]",
                "showGroupTotal": false
            },     
            {
                "level": "[Product].[Int Product Name].[Int Product Name]",
                "showGroupTotal": false
            },
            {
                "level": "[Product].[Local Product Name].[Local Product Name]",
                "showGroupTotal": false
            }]
}
```

both are valid jsons, giving same data but my application can read only the later one. So, i have to convert first one to second one. I have lots of data like this. How can i do this pragmatically or is there any workaround on this ?

Comment: Actually, neither is valid JSON. You're missing a containing `{}`.

Comment: Its a part of ths JSON and i missed the {} right, i only took the part that i need to reformat

Answer (score 0):

You must have bracket "{}"

> {
>   "row_elements": [
>           {
>               "level": "[Product].[Corporation].[Corporation]",
>               "showGroupTotal": false
>           },
>           {
>               "level": "[Product].[Int Product Name].[Int Product Name]",
>               "showGroupTotal": false
>           },
>           {
>               "level": "[Product].[Local Product Name].[Local Product Name]",
>               "showGroupTotal": false
>           }]
>   }

Comment: I have bracket elements but thats not the question, i need to reformat to add an extra member to every Group and add add Showgroup total false below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string json = @"
{
    ""row_elements"": [
        ""[Product].[Corporation].[Corporation]"",
        ""[Product].[Int Product Name].[Int Product Name]"",
        ""[Product].[Local Product Name].[Local Product Name]""
    ]
}";

JObject rootObj = JObject.Parse(json);

JArray array = new JArray();
foreach (JToken token in rootObj["row_elements"].Children())
{
    JObject item = new JObject();
    item.Add("level", token);
    item.Add("showGroupTotal", false);
    array.Add(item);
}

JObject output = new JObject();
output.Add("row_elements", array);

string newJson = output.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(newJson);
```

Output:

```
{
  "row_elements": [
    {
      "level": "[Product].[Corporation].[Corporation]",
      "showGroupTotal": false
    },
    {
      "level": "[Product].[Int Product Name].[Int Product Name]",
      "showGroupTotal": false
    },
    {
      "level": "[Product].[Local Product Name].[Local Product Name]",
      "showGroupTotal": false
    }
  ]
}
```